# Contructor accepts other intitialization types than what is defined?

Tags: c++, class, initialization

How can a class constructor accept an object as initialization when it is expecting in int?
Please explain to me like I'm five years old how the line 'A b(a)' is accepted by the compiler,
when the constructor seems to be expecting (int x)? Many thanks in advance.

```
class A
{
   public:
       int v;
       A(int x) : v(x + 1) {} //apparently == v = x+1...
       int get() const { return v; } //stays const after initialization
};


int main()
{
  A a(2); //Init by int, ok
  A b(a); //Init by object??
}
```

Comment: You never told the compiler *not* to provide the default copy-constructor which, apparently, you don't want?

Comment: Because there is a compiler generated [**copy constructor**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) that will be used for `A b(a);`

Comment: @user17732522 `a` is an `A`.

Comment: You can add this in the class in order to delete the compiler generated copy constructor: `A(A&) = delete;`

Answer (score 3):

> how the line 'A b(a)' is accepted by the compiler

The compiler will implicitly synthesize(generate) a [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) `A::A(const A&)` for your class which will be used for `A b(a);`.

In case you want to disallow `A b(a);`, you can use `delete` to mark the copy constructor deleted as shown below:

```
class A
{
   public:
       int v;
       A(int x) : v(x + 1) {} 
       int get() const { return v; } 
       A(const A&) = delete;//added this
};
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/bHQkamZwL)